Customize envelope completed email format in Docusign
I am using Docusign API to send envelopes to the signers to sign the document.
I have a requirement where, after all the signers have signed, I want to send an email to a another user (whom I am keeping in CC) and this CCed user is last in the routing order.
As expected the CCed user is getting an email after all the signers have signed, but I want to customize the Email blurb of the CCed user.
I have used the below property while creating envelope to customize email blurb to CCed user
emailNotification: {
              emailSubject: 'Completed',
              emailBody: 'All users have completed signing. Please review the document',
              supportedLanguage: 'en'
            }

But the above emailBody is replaced with "All parties have completed document". I am assuming that the Docusign is overriding my customized emailBody when the CCed user is the last person in the routing order.
Is there any way I can customize my own emailBody if the CCed user is last person in signing order

The above code you showed is for the initial email, not the envelope completed email. CC recipients also get an email when it's their turn in the routing order to tell them this envelope is on route, which should have this customization you have. If they are last, then perhaps the system wisely only sent them a single email, the one you didn't customize.
You can customize this email through the resource file - https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=yum1583277332870.html&_LANG=enus
This guide have all the details - https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus
See page 92/93 for what you need:


Thank you so much Inbar Gazit for taking your time to send me the reference. This is what I am looking for.
